# How to add static tableviewcells on runtime in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new in objective C.

I am using an static table view controller to load data related to my Class GAME.

I have 2 sections, in one section are cells related to the game, and in the last section y want to add the players who were in the game, which can be as many as I want. For this I created a button in the last cell of the first section `addPlayer`.

I want to create a new row in the 2nd section each time I touch `addPlayer`. how can I achieve this?

[image]

Thanks!

PD: Do I need to have the first row of the section 2 added by story board? Don't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add cells each time you add a player you could have, for example, a `NSmutableArray` which will contain the players and when you create a player you add it to that array and call the table's `[yourTable realoadData]` method. Then, your `UITableViewController cellForRowAtIndexpath:` method should loop through that array and add the cells dynamically. Use the array's count to keep track of the indexPath. You might have to keep track of the section so that you add the initial cells of the first section (the Date cell, the Pozo cell and the button cell) Keep in mind you will need to add a prototype cell in the Storyboard and set its identifier so that you may reuse the cell otherwise you will have to keep creating and adding cells to the table, which is not efficient.

Let me know if it works or if you have more questions!

Comment: But i can have an static section and a dynamic section in the same view? If i put dynamic cells i cant use sections?

Comment: You could "cheat" those static cells in, for example: have the MutableArray start with 3 dud objects, then add your players, later, when the calling the cellForRowAtIndexPath, you could check the indexPath and the dud objects, if(indexpath ==1) then add you first static cell to the first section and repeat for numbers 2 and 3. Afterwards when you add your players indexPath will have a value of 4 and so will your player array.

Comment: And the section look and feel can be cheated?

Comment: Yes, as long as you reload the table's data, try something like this: -cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 if(indexPath == 1){ add first cell to first section}
 else if (indexPath == 2){ second cell }
 
 else{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
  cell.playerlabel.text = [playerArray[indexPath.row] name]
  //add the cell to your second section 
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can't add static rows at runtime, you should go for dynamics. 
What you can do, but only if you are using a Table View Controller, is create the maximum number of rows that you need, and override the – tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: to return zero height rows, at the indexPath that you don't need to show.